# Is there an XSS risk putting unsanitized user input in a text input?

Tags: html, forms, security, xss

I understand it is useful to sanitize user input when you display it on your site, using a function like htmlentities() in php. But would something like this present an XSS risk?

```
<input type="text" value="<?=user input drawn from the database?>" />
```

Would it be better to sanitize the input like this?

```
<input type="text" value="<?=htmlentities(user input drawn from the database)?>" />
```

I should specify that I'm only talking about the security risk of input value attributes, I know I still have to sanitize user input if I want to display it elsewhere on the site.

Comment: There might be a risk if you do not specify the encoding to `htmlentities`. (Why does everyone use `htmlentites` instead of `htmlspecialchars`?)

Comment: `<?php print htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>` as `htmlspecialchars($string)` and `htmlentities($string)` pose a possible unicode risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could enter text like this,

```
escape!" /><script>alert("I escaped, because you didn't escape!");</script><img src="
```

which would give you the following output: (Formatted for readability)

```
<input type="text" value="escape!" />
<script>
    alert("I escaped, because you didn't escape!");
</script>
<img src="" />
```

You are just concatenating strings, not manipulating the DOM, so you still need to watch out for quotes.

Answer (score 3):

possibly yes, consider the user input from database may have double quotation mark.

you should use `htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);` to convert quotation marks.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 1):

```
But would something like this present an XSS risk?
```

Yes, something like that would present an XSS risk **as long as the data hasn't been already sanitized** before inserting it in the database.

```
Would it be better to sanitize the input like this?
```

Yes, it is trivial to sanitize every user input before displaying it on a webpage. Also take a look at [htmlspecialchars()](http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Comment: Why would it present an XSS risk if no html is processed? For instance, if I set an text input value to something like "<strong>sample text</strong>", the input box displays the text as is, not **sample text**.